# How to convert a string to standard input?

Tags: python

I only want a simple python calculator script. I named it calc.py.
I just want it to take a keyboard input from the user. E.g. 7/4*6
Then print it: `print(7/4*6)`.
The example should return 10.5.
However, this is my code. It takes the input as a string so it just prints 7/4*6, not 10.5.

```
#!/bin/python3

answer=input("Type an arithmetic operation: ")

print(answer)
```

So I want to convert the `answer` into a standard input.

Comment: That's not at all what the term standard input means

Comment: You can use the eval function. like print(eval(answer))

Comment: @mousetail I will figure it one day.